# How is encoding of strings determined in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I am running the exact same code (and connection strings, etc.) on two different computer (fetched from source control).

The code queries a DB (using Dapper), and reads strings from it.

However, the behavior regarding accents is not the same.

On machine A, the DB string `'régime'` is fetched as `'régime'`

On machine B, the DB string `'régime'` is fetched as `'r�gime'` (U+FFFD).

The behavior seems to be determined at compile time (ie. if I compile the code on machine A, and run it on machine B, it reads the string correctly, and if I compile it on machine B and run it on machine A, it does not).

I am running out of ideas... Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Strings in C# are always (internally) encoded as UTF-16. This likely has nothing to do with the language and everything with the data layer code (that is, Dapper and/or SQL Server itself), or even possibly your presentation code or your console code page. Without more context it's hard to tell. For starters, verify you're using the same version of the Dapper package on both machines.

Comment: And compare the DB schema's side by side. Post the colum definitons.

Comment: If you are getting the string from a file at runtime it would be interestig to look at the file after compile time and see if one file was modified and resaved with a different encoding  header after the compile process. As in are the text files produced the same at a binary level from the two systems. If you are reading this name from a file.

Comment: I think this needs a [mcve]. See if you can eliminate Dapper.

Comment: You didn't actually provide any info. What database (sql server, postresql,...), what column type? Code you use to query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the two machines did not use the same version of the ADO Driver to connect to the database, off by one version.

The patch note for the new version reads:

> None standard characters in DataProvider display question mark

Disabling 'Copy Local' for the reference allowed to get a consisted behavior for a single machine, no matter where the program was compiled.

Answer (score 2):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx

> In the .NET Framework 4 and previous versions, by default, the culture of all threads is set to the Windows system culture

It goes on to say that in versions after 4 the app domain default culture is null.  Followed by this:

> Unless it is set explicitly, the value of the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property is null, and the culture of threads in an application domain that have not been assigned an explicit culture is defined by the default Windows system culture.

Meaning if you haven't explicitly set the app domain's default culture, all threads inheriting that value will use the Windows System culture setting, regardless of .net framework version.

I suspect you did not explicitly define the culture for the thread in which problem operation runs.

In this case the culture for the thread is based on the Windows System Culture defined on the machine where it was compiled.

Try both locating the system culture setting on the two machines in question, and explicitly defining the culture for the thread.

Specific to the ENCODING part of your question:

> U+FFFD � REPLACEMENT CHARACTER used to replace an unknown, unrecognized or unrepresentable character

Key here being unrepresentable due to the culture setting.

Comment: All this is about runtime behaviour. The OP claims it is determined at compile-time.

Comment: The behavior suggests that determining the system's default culture is done at compile time.  I am not finding anything that definitively confirms or refutes this.  Everything does say that, the fetching of the culture specific resources is done at runtime.  Based on it working on both computers if the code is compiled on Machine A, it is safe to say that both machines have the culture data, but on Machine B the application is not choosing the correct one as the default.  You can see many different culture info packages in windows file system.  The app just says which to read from.